Formula relating the Riemann zeta function and Euler's constant
In the digital library of mathematical formulas I have found the equation:
$$\zeta(1+s)=\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-s-1}\left(\gamma+\psi(1+x)\right)dx$$
for $0<Re(s)<1$, where $\psi(x):=\frac{d}{dx}\ln\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$ is the Digamma function and $\gamma:=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+
  \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n)\right)$ is Euler's constant.
This is supposed to be proven in the article "Integralen voor de $\zeta$-functie van Riemann" Bruijn, de, N. G. (1937).
I have found the text, but the proof starts with the following formula (end of page 176, equation 20)
$$\frac{1}{a^s}=\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dy}{y^s(y+a)}$$
said to be true for $0<Re(s)<1$ and $a>0$.
This is obtained starting from the equation:
$$\frac{1}{a^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-ay}y^{s-1}sy$$
true for $Re(s)>0$ and $a>0$, equation 2 page 170, also used and proved true in Titchmarsh's "The theory of the Riemann zeta function".
Combined with the special case:
$$y^{s-1}=\frac{1}{y^{(1-s)}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-s)}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-xy}\frac{dx}{x^s}$$
Using these equations together would give us:
$$\frac{1}{a^s}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s)}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-ay}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-xy}\frac{dx}{x^s}dy$$
If one could exchange the order of integration, we would obtain the formula above (20).
My problem is that this is not justified in the paper and I have found that, if we plug in the first equation $a=1>0$ and $s=0,2$ so that $Re(s)>0$ we find
$$\frac{1}{1^{0,2}}=1=\frac{\sin(\pi (0,2))}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dy}{y^{0,2}(y+1)}$$
But the right side is a complex number!
I don't understand if there is something wrong with the equation or I am making some kind of mistake, can anyone help me out?

The right-hand side is also $1$. Exchanging the order of integration is permitted because of absolute convergence.

Also, taking $y=at$, $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm d}y}}{{y^s (y + a)}}}  = \frac{1}{{a^s }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{t^s (t + 1)}}}  = \frac{1}{{a^s }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{t^s (t + 1)}}}  \= \frac{1}{{a^s }}B(1 - s,s) = \frac{1}{{a^s }}\frac{{\Gamma (1 - s)\Gamma (s)}}{{\Gamma (1)}} = \frac{1}{{a^s }}\frac{\pi }{{\sin (\pi s)}}.
$$

Okay, thank you, my real difficulty was tho in the next formula. in the paper it says that it follows that
$$\frac{1}{k^{(s+1)}}=\frac{\sin(\pi s)}{\pi s} \int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{dy}{y^s(k+y)^2}$$
This seems to be easily obtainable by integration by parts, but when I proceed to do it I find the term:
$-\frac{y^{-s}}{s}*\frac{1}{k+y}|^{\infty}_{0}$
that doesn't leave just zero.

Differentiate both sides of the original equation with respect to $a$, and then take $a=k$.

Okay, that works thank you!
